# Tools to e2e test compiled binaries in integrated dockerized environment?

Tags: tools, e2e

After searching for tools to do the test of user scenarios, grade e2e, of binaries fully installed in their environment (meaning containers... Docker), I found nothing that looks match my needs.

So it's no orchestration, which would be on top of it. It's also not the tool that you could install on a machine to do the tests. I think I'm searching for a framework to test if docker based images have to proper outputs.

Docker has no output? Yeah, that's my question. How to make it so? Is their already a framework that thought to every of that?

Inputs:

- Docker image
- case data (files)
- scenarios (scripts)

Outputs:

- return values
- files
- container (not deleted, just in case)

Or am I totally thinking it sideways?

It's NOT web, NOT api, NOT user interfaces.

Comment: How is the tool Giving out put ? Is it printing to console ? Or a file ? If it's printing to console you can access the docker logs and get those data

Comment: Files inside container can be copied with [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) or accessed via a shared volume.

Answer (score 1):

How is the tool Giving output ? Is it printing to console? Or a file?. You can access docker outputs by the following methods.

1. If tool/SUT(service under test) is printing to console you can access the docker logs and get those data.

   `docker logs -f`
2. IF output is stored to a file say ./output.txt Access that file

   `docker cp <target_path> <destination_path>`
3. Create an API service or webserver in docker, Expose a docker port and access those files using the API service or url. THe below command let you access your docker service running on localhost:80 from h=your host system through localhost:8080.

   `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080/tcp ubuntu bash`
4. You can mount the docker to a host volume

   `docker volume create logdata
   docker run -it --name volume1 --mount type=volume,source=<volumename>,target=<target> microsoft/windowsservercore powershell`

**Read more about bindings:**

https://4sysops.com/archives/introduction-to-docker-bind-mounts-and-volumes/

**Read more about docker run options:**

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/